# Why doesn't my font.name property affect the fonts on ppt made using Python-pptx? I always get arial font

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

So I'm trying to write some program to convert html to pptx using Python.
I'm using some code to parse through the file and then format text at run level.

I am using 2 textframes on a blank slide to work, the first textframe is used for title and 2nd one is used for rendering the body of html.

But no matter what I do (Paragraph.font.name or run.font.name), I am always getting Arial font in my 2nd textframe.

I've tried to update the fontnames by looping over tf.paragraphs and also by looping over all runs (paragraph.runs) nothing seems to work.

Here is my function which I use for setting the font

```
def setFont(font,tags,fontStyle,size):
    font.language_id = MSO_LANGUAGE_ID.HEBREW
    font.size = Pt(size)
    font.name = fontStyle
    for tag in tags:
        if tag == 'b':
            font.bold = True
        elif tag == 'i':
            font.italic = True
        elif tag == 'u':
            font.underline = True
    return font
```

and here is my main calling function (I've removed some other calls which are not directly related to python-pptx)

```
def makeSlide(prs,title,body,fontStyle,titleSize,bodySize):

    #Add title Slide
    blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
    width = height = Inches(8)

    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(1), Inches(0.5), Inches(8), Inches(1))
    tf = txBox.text_frame

    tf.text = title

    tf.paragraphs[0].font.size=Pt(titleSize)
    tf.paragraphs[0].font.bold = True
    tf.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,0,0)
    tf.paragraphs[0].font.name = fontStyle
    tf.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER

    styles = MY_CUSTOM_HTML_BODY_PARSER() #Removed this part from here, its just a parser which gives output in a desired format



    #Start 2nd textbox for body
    txBox2 = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(0.5), Inches(1.7), Inches(9), Inches(5.5))
    tf = txBox2.text_frame
    tf.clear()
    tf.word_wrap = True
    tf.paragraphs[0].text = ''
    tf.paragraphs[0].font.name = fontStyle
    paragraph = tf.add_paragraph()
    paragraph.alignment = alignment

    #Loop over styles (Tag info and render pptx accordingly)
    new_line = True
    level = 0
    number = 0
    for _ in styles:
     #Can ignore this part, I'm just checking to see if I have to go on a new line or not
        if _ == '\n':
            paragraph = tf.add_paragraph()
            paragraph.alignment = alignment
            new_line = True
        else:
            tags = _[1]
        #Can also ignore this, I'm checking to see if I have to be on next level in lists or not 
        #(I use custom bullet function, since python-pptx doesn't have a function for numbered bullets.
            if _[1].count('ul') > 1 or _[1].count('ol') > 1 or _[1].count('ul') + _[1].count('ol') > 1:
                level = 1
                if new_line:
                    paragraph.level = level
                    level = 0
                else:
                    paragraph = tf.add_paragraph()
                    paragraph.alignment = alignment
                    paragraph.level = level
                    level = 0
                    new_line = True
            if new_line:
                run = paragraph.add_run()
            #Custom bullet function as u can see I send in fontStyle here and apply style inside function
                run,number = addBullets(run,tags,bodySize-3,number,fontStyle)
                new_line = False

            run = paragraph.add_run()
            run.text = parser.words_styles[_[0]][0]
            font = run.font
            #SetFont function Defined above
            font = setFont(font,tags,fontStyle,bodySize)
            new_line = False

    for paragraph in tf.paragraphs:
        paragraph.font.name = fontStyle
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            if run.font.name != fontStyle:
                print(run.text)
    #return slide
    return slide
```

I'm not quite sure where I am doing wrong, would appreciate any help, I can clean up code more if that's needed.

Comment: Reduce your code to the single simplest example that doesn't work and show your exact inputs and exact outputs. Start with trying to make it work at the run level; the paragraph level is ignored by PowerPoint sometimes. And use a font-name that you know renders correctly in the file (because you've made a shape that displays in that font by hand and have inspected the XML for PowerPoint's version of the font-name). PowerPoint can only show fonts that are installed on the machine at rendering time. The names have to be just right since it finds them by str comparison and can't fix misspellings.

Comment: @scanny The thing is, I tried doing all that but I am unable to pinpoint the problem and to further complicate the issue if I upload the ppt to google slides I see correct fonts. So I am not even sure what is wrong anymore.

Comment: To add another thing, If I open the presentation using python-pptx and loop over all text (Using the code in quickstart documentation) and print run.font.name, I get my font name.

Comment: @scanny

So I made a copy of the ppt generated using the program, and changed it's text manually by using ms office.

Then I extracted both ppts to compare the XML file, I see a lot more lines added to the file.

https://imgur.com/a/ZCCM0QZ 

Left is python-pptx, right is manually changing the font.

I'll admit I don't know how to navigate this but if maybe you can understand something here, maybe it has some info as to why the fonts not being rendered properly?

If not could you point me to some site where I can read more about the structure?

Comment: I've found the line which causes the font to change, its this one: https://imgur.com/a/AoOTZ0y 

What is that line? and how do I make sure that it changes using python-pptx?

Comment: After some googling, I've found that it's for "complex script", According to the documentation here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-font-typeface.html, This should also change when I do font.name but why is this value not in my XML files generated using python-pptx?

How can I ensure that this line gets added?